# Visitor pattern with two method parameters

Tags: java, oop

I have a class `MethodClass` and classes `Foo` and `Bar` that both extend `FooBar`. MethodClass has a list containing objects of  `Foo` and `Bar` and a  method `doMethod()` that picks two random elements out of this list and passes them to `doMethod(FooBar fooBar1, FooBar fooBar2)`. The result of `doMethod(FooBar fooBar1, FooBar fooBar2)` depends on the subclasses of the given arguments.

The structure thus far:

**Class MethodClass:**

```
List<Foobar> list;

void doMethod() {
    FooBar obj1 = ...;
    FooBar obj2 = ...;
    doMethod(obj1,obj2);

void doMethod(FooBar fooBar1, FooBar fooBar2) {
     //instance checking and downcasting
    ...
}

void doMethod(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {
    foo1.doA();
    foo2.doA();
}

void doMethod(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    foo.doB();
    bar.doB();
}

void doMethod(Bar bar1, Bar bar2) {
    bar1.doA();
    bar2.doA();
}
```

**Abstract Class FooBar:**

```
public abstract class FooBar {
    abstract void methodA() {...}
    abstract void methodB() {...}
}
```

**Class Foo:**

```
public class Foo extends FooBar {
    void methodB() {...}
    void methodB() {...}
}
```

**Class Bar:**

```
public class Foo extends FooBar {
    void methodA() {...}
    void methodB() {...}
}
```

---

I will further extend `FooBar` in the future (The subclasses will only have `methodA` and `methodB`). Is it possible to achieve this without donwcasting and without the need of updating more than one class when adding a subclass to `FooBar`? If `doMethod` took only one argument this would be easily done using a variant of a visitor pattern but I can't find a proper way to scale it up to two arguments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I will further extend FooBar in the future.

So the visitor pattern is not the best choice as it is designed to define new operations without changing the model and not the reverse.

Besides, actually you invoke different methods according to the specific subclass of the parameter such as :

```
void doMethod(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) {
    foo1.doA();
    foo2.doA();
}

void doMethod(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    foo.doB();
    bar.doB();
}
```

It is like whether according to the subclass of the elements picked from the list you would perform a distinct operation.
So polymorphism (base of the visitor pattern but also of the most of design patterns) will not be helpful here.
To benefit from the polymorphism, you should provide a higher abstraction level.

Your requirement is broad and very abstract. So I cannot give you more specific pointers but anyway I think that you should review the overall design and focus on the consistency between the behaviors defined by the subclasses.